# How to fix this yum dependency requirement and install python?

Tags: centos, python, yum

```
bash-4.2# yum install openscap-containers
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openscap-containers.noarch 0:1.3.3-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 3.6 for package: openscap-containers-1.3.3-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python3 for package: openscap-containers-1.3.3-1.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/python3 for package: openscap-containers-1.3.3-1.el7.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: openscap-containers-1.3.3-1.el7.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:openscapmaint:openscap-latest)
           Requires: python(abi) = 3.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-88.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python34-3.4.10-4.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
               python(abi) = 3.4
Error: Package: openscap-containers-1.3.3-1.el7.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:openscapmaint:openscap-latest)
           Requires: /usr/bin/python3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Even when I install python3 and am able to use it at `/usr/bin/python3` it says I do not meet the requirements.

```
bash-4.2# yum install rh-python36
bash-4.2# ln -s /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 2):

Capability `python(abi) = 3.6` and file `/usr/bin/python3` are provided by `python3` package in the base repository ([reference](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/python3-3.6.8-13.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)).

You should run `yum install openscap-containers` while the base repository is enabled.

Since `yum` didn't pick it up as dependency, you have a problem that the base repository was disabled or its repo definition is missing.

In the latter case, `yum reinstall centos-release`.